# Same line text not aligned vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 component on a ligne, but it's not aligned vertically.
I tried to use vertical-align but that don't change the text.

Like we can see, Injection is not aligned vertically with Period.
[image]

I created a demo

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-lable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="injection" id="injection">Injection</label>
    <label for="period" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Période (sem)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number" min="0" value="52" class="form-control" id="year" name="period" placeholder="Entrer la période en semaine" data-fv-integer="true" data-fv-integer-message="La valeur doit être numérique">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1ss81reg/

Also, i remarked then if i reduce and grow the windows, sizing of component

Big screen

[image]

Medium

[image]

Small

[image]

Small screen should  like the big one
Big screen should like the medium one.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure doesn't make sense; you have `columns` and `rows` nested inside each other (which shouldn't be necessary anyway) and aren't using any `container` element in conjunction. Also, `rows` aren't needed with [form-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) since `form-group` is used in it's place.

See working example Snippet. Maybe this will help.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div role="tabpanel">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="enable"><a href="#medicalTab" data-toggle="tab">Médical</a>

    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="enable"><a href="#medicalTab2" data-toggle="tab">Médical 2</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id='content' class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="medicalTab">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="lodgerMedicalContactDivTemplate"></div>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="medicate" id="medicate">Médicale</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="diabete" id="diabete">Diabète</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" name="injection" id="injection">Injection</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="year" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Période (sem)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" value="52" id="year" name="period" placeholder="Entrer la période en semaine">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="medicalDrawer" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tiroir médicale</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select id="medicalDrawer" name="medicalDrawerId" class="form-control"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="lodgerMedicalSave">Sauvegarder</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="medicalTab2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```